# Latex compile suddenly turned into status that never ends

Tags: compiling, texmaker

I was using latex it worked properly, now when again I wanted to build the text, compiling never ends.
from the step that it compiled normally to now that it does not finish compiling, I did not make a major change, or did not add a big text or etc!

When I press quick build or even try user defined build, mouse scroll changes into a rotating circle which means it is compiling, but compiling never ends.

I am using Texmaker on ubuntu,and even I reinstalled all its packages, still there is the problem.

Has anyone had same experience?

Am I doing a silly mistake?

Comment: Remove the `.aux` and `.toc` file, for example

Comment: Translated into meaningful terms: My car worked yesterday, but today when I try it doesn't start at all. What's happening? ...it could be anything, literally. We need more information (says the crystal ball).

Comment: Welcome! Compile from the command line interactively to see when it hangs. Use ctrl+c to interrupt the hang and get a clue about what is happening. If that doesn't track it down, the only thing you can do is the usual: comment out most of your document, check it compiles, uncomment some, check, uncomment some, check .... etc. until you find the problem. Without a minimal example which produces the issue when compiled, we can't tell you what's wrong. Hanging is not very common, but it happens. It is reasonably common with XeTeX specifically (at least for me).

Comment: @cfr I did so, and even I switched to a simple code that worked previously, and ran that one it gives this
Process started
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2013/Debian) The top-level auxiliary file: egypro-template.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file egypro-template.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file egypro-template.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file egypro-template.aux (There were 3 error messages)
Process exited with error(s)

Comment: @cfr I think there is something wrong with my latex on ubunut, but as I said I even reinstalled many packages from synaptic, and do not know what else to do.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I did so, nothing happened, I think there is something wrong with my latex on ubunut, but as I said I even reinstalled many packages from synaptic, and do not know what else to do.

Comment: I even reinstalled, bib packages through synaptic on ubuntu, still there is problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeX is a programming language and you can write endless loops in it. A toy example is this one

```
% an endless loop in TeX
\def\a{\b}
\def\b{\a}
\a  % You need to call \a to trigger the endless loop
    % The circular definition alone isn't enough
```

Now your task is to find the trigger of the endless loop. When you have some kind of version control, compare the last working version with the looping one, and look for what you have added.

Without version control, try to find a minimal endless loop (or a maximal document that still works) to pin it down. When you need more help, ask again here presenting your findings.

Comment: You're right! One should be aware of this when doing global Search&Replace - I replaced a shortcut definition by itself :)

Answer (score 0):

Two files had been automatically generated with .bbl .blg and I do not know from where. When I deleted them it worked fine again.

Comment: Presumably, you ran BibTeX or Biber at some point. (Messages above suggest BibTeX.)

Comment: I had a similar issue with pdflatex and Biber always starting again recursively. Probably this was caused (at least in my case) by changed .bib-file. If I remember it right, I changed a bibkey in the .bib-file as well as my document and then ran the pdflatex-Biber-2xpdflatex cycle which never ended. But I was able to solve this problem by simply running Biber alone and then rerunning the pdflatex-Biber-cycle.